# Clustered / Non-clustered for non-composite keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

When having a non-composite key in a table, would it make any sense to set it as either clustered or non-clustered? For example assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logins]
(
     [Customer_Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Customers(Customer_Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     [Email] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
     [Password] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)
```

Since the `Customer_Id` makes use of a sequential unique identifier, then there's no reason to make any other key as clustered. But from my viewpoint this would be beneficial if the other key is a composite key for example such as `CONSTRAINT [Table_UK] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Email, OrderId)`.

However, I am unsure if a non-composite key as I represented can also benefit from being non-clustered to save database performance (saving the trouble for sorting etc, as the sequential key is inherently sorted)

Comment: Your definition of `Customer_Id` does not produce sequential GUIDs - you need to add `default newsequentialid()`, but even then it's not guaranteed as the guid sequence is reset when you reboot windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786(v=sql.110).aspx).  You can always reorganize an index if it becomes too fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one clustered index on a table, so all other indexes are most always non-clustered, but never clustered. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx for more information.